# unable to detect objects in image from lg-simulator by using Yolo.v3

Tags: opencv, object-detection, yolo

i have implemented yolo v3, trained from cocodata set. it is working perfectly for all cases except when i use it to detect cars in an image from lg-simulator. only different thing here is that image from lg simulator is very zoomed in, by using cv2.imread. i am unable to see the the whole picture. i have tried to resize the image and then feed it to trained model but it does not work. i have played with cv2.blobfromimage also but nothing seems to be working for me.
i have downloaded other pictures from internet of the same lg simulator but they are working fine. but why not from the image i have taken myself. please let me know how can i solve the matter.

Comment: make sure your object after resize has similar characteristics - size, lighting, vehicle type. If any of those are far enough from the training data you can't expect detections.

Comment: okay. so are there any ways to manipulate these properties? i have also tried to change the threshold level but is very very far from training data i guess

Comment: as you noticed the scale can be directly manipulated, lighting can also to some extent.  If its important to detect your own images you might want to generate a lot of them and use them as training data